# Disable postgres replication but keep slave server up as own individual server

Tags: postgresql

We currently have a postgres server on AWS pulling updates from an internal server.  We want to stop the replication, but keep the data on both the internal and the AWS server - the internal server is no longer being updated.

Is it just a case of removing the

```
host replication replicator x.x.x.x/32 md5
```

line from the pg_hba.conf file on both master and slave and restarting Postgres?

and then running

```
pg_ctl -D /target_directory promote
```

on the old slave server to promote the read only slave to a read / write master.

Answer (score 0):

You should drop replication slot on master db. (physical replication)

```
SELECT pg_drop_replication_slot('your_slot_name');
```

Then promote replica server.

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl promote -D /pg_data/12/main/
```

Edit pg_hab.file, remove replication line and run on master `select pg_reload_conf();`.

Comment: So run 

SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots ;

and then

pg_drop_replication_slot: